# Get mx:AdvancedDataGrid Selected Item

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, selecteditem

I am having a heck of a time getting my id value from the XML item associated with the selected DataGrid row.

[image]

It is strange because I get the selectedObject XML no problem, but for some reason I can't get the id out of it.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider='{pData}' sortExpertMode="true" id="myDataGrid" 
                                 width="100%" height="120" paddingLeft="0" dragEnabled="true"
                                 selectionMode="multipleCells" allowMultipleSelection="true"
                                 keyUp="onSelection(event)" mouseUp="onSelection(event)"
                                 draggableColumns="false"  >

private function onSelection(event:Event):void
        {

            for each(var s:Series in myBarChart2.series){
                // initialize/empty dataTipItems of all series.
                s.dataTipItems = [];
            }
            // For each of the selected cells to show multiple data tips at once    
            var n:int = event.currentTarget.selectedCells.length;

            var selectedObject:XML = event.target.data;
            var theId = selectedObject.playerStats.id.toString();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
// Important note:::  The first element of XML is omitted when find this.
            currentPlayer = event.target.data;
            var theId = currentPlayer.id;
```